# Executing an equijoin as a natural join

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

I am new to SQL.

I wish to execute a query involving two tables as both an equijoin and a natural join, where I am counting the instances customers placed orders by city. I am assuming that a customer has placed an order if their customer ID is appearing in the `ordertable` relation.

I am trying to combine equijoin, `COUNT()` and GROUP BY in one query, then repeat the same query by using `NATURAL JOIN` in another.

Please refer to the code below for my attempts and their results.

The following equijoin:

```
SELECT customer.city, COUNT(*) AS total FROM customer, ordertable
WHERE customer.cust_id = ordertable.cust_id
GROUP BY customer.city
ORDER BY customer.city ASC
;
```

yields

1. City |   Count
2. SF   | 1
3. SLC  | 7
4. Tucson | 2

But:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM customer
NATURAL JOIN orderline
GROUP BY customer.city, city
ORDER BY customer.city ASC
;
```

yields

1. City| Total
2. LA | 34
3. SF |17
4. SLC |    170
5. Tucson | 34

I believe the first set of results are correct, but I don't understand why the two different approaches yield different results.

Comment: I would avoid both types and use a proper `JOIN ON` clause. The first style is no longer "standard" and the second doesn't show what specific columns are being used for the `JOIN`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges and illustrating why `natural join`s should be avoided.  Simply do not use them.

The query that you should learn is:

```
SELECT c.city, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM customer c JOIN
     ordertable ot
     ON c.cust_id = ot.cust_id
GROUP BY c.city
ORDER BY c.city ASC;
```

Your second query is joining to a *different* table, `orderline`, which does not have a `cust_id`.  So, the "natural join" is generating a Cartesian product.

Note the following:

- The `join` is explicit in the `from` clause.
- The `join` conditions are explicit in the query.  No guessing.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

I consider the `natural join` to be an abomination, because it does not take properly declared foreign key relationships into account.  Instead, it simply relies on the naming conventions of the columns to match tables.

And, problems that should result in an error -- such as a missing `join` key are not detected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact that I used the wrong relation. It's irritating that no error was thrown up when the `cust_id` column was not detected. I'll never touch `NATURAL JOIN` again.